# ComboBox is disabled after using visibility property

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, combobox, powerpoint

I am developing a PowerPoint based application with a drop-down combo box. It works.
Then, when certain conditions are fulfilled, I want to hide the combo box (an object in the PowerPoint presentation), so the user does not try to use it. I do it by `.Visibility = msoFalse`. When I want the box to show, I am using `.Visibility = msoTrue`.
However, when the combo box appears, the drop-down button seems different than originally (not a triangle. see attached screen shot) and more importantly it does not respond to clicking on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The property should be .Visible rather than .Visibilty

I can't repro the problem you decscribe here, though (PPT 2016, 32-bit).
As a test:
Create a new presentation with only one slide.
Add a combobox and a rectangle to the slide.
Add this code to a module then assign the rectangle an action setting of Run Macro: TestThis.
Then see what happens when you go into slide show view and click the rectangle a few times.

```
Sub TestThis()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("ComboBox1")
    oSh.Visible = Not oSh.Visible
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (1)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Steve,
You are obviously correct regarding the .Visible property. This is what I have been trying and this is what I have experienced the problem with.
I am going to try your suggestion and report back my success.

Comment: Well, Steve Rindsberg, this is becoming more interesting.
As a stand alone program, your code works fine. When I added this Sub to my code and linked it to a virtual button, the ComboBox keeps showing on the screen (with the drop-down menu), even after running the Sub. However, when I exit the slide-show mode the shape is not visible on the slide (depending on the number of times I clicked the button - even or odd).

Comment: @Altame What's a "virtual button"? I'm not familiar with that term. In any case, with some PPT installs, a simple GoToSlide won't force the slide to refresh. In that case, add a "dummy" shape, say a rectangle, to the slide (even off screen in some cases), do the GoToSlide, then delete the rectangle. The user will never see any of this happen but it can force a refresh.